# R: How to solve Error in is.data.frame(x):object ' ' not found?

Tags: r, csv, tweets

I tried to save my tweets into .csv, but I faced this error message:

```
lina=twListToDF(maulina)
Called from: twListToDF(maulina)
write.csv(lina,file='D:/maulina.csv',row.names=F)
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'lina' not found
```

What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `debug` set on `twListToDF`

`undebug(twListToDF)`, then try again

Comment: I have tried `undebug(twListToDF)`, and I got warning message `Browse[3]> undebug(twListToDF)
Warning message:
In undebug(fun) : argument is not being debugged`

Comment: hmm... perhaps try showing more of what is going on.  Session info, os, etc.  Try running from terminal, but using `R --vanilla` and see if you can reproduce the problem.