# mgcv::gamm() and MuMIn::dredge() errors

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I've been trying to fit multiple GAMs using the package `mgcv` within a function, and crudely select the most appropriate model through model selection procedures. But my function runs the first model then doesn't seem to recognise the input data `dat` again.

I get the error

> Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'dat' not found.

I think this is a scoping problem and I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298754/r-how-to-solve-error-in-is-data-framexobject-not-found), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148533/is-data-framedata-object-not-found-in-function-context) for help but cannot figure it out.

Code and data are as follows (hopefully reproducible): 
https://github.com/cwaldock1/Help/blob/master/test_gam.csv

```
library(mgcv)

# Function to fit multiple models 
best.mod <- function(dat) {

# Set up control structure
ctrl <- list(niterEM = 0, msVerbose = TRUE, optimMethod="L-BFGS-B")

# AR(1)
m1 <- get.models(dredge(gamm(Temp ~ s(Month, bs = "cc") + s(Date, bs = 'cr') + Year,
         data = dat, correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|Year, p = 1),
         control = ctrl)), subset=1)[[1]]

# AR(2)
m2 <- get.models(dredge(gamm(Temp ~ s(Month, bs = "cc") + s(Date, bs = 'cr') + Year,
         data = dat, correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|Year, p = 2),
         control = ctrl)), subset=1)[[1]]

# AR(3)
m3 <- get.models(dredge(gamm(Temp ~ s(Month, bs = "cc") + s(Date, bs = 'cr') + Year,
         data = dat, correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|Year, p = 3),
         control = ctrl)), subset = 1)[[1]]


### Select best model to work with based on unselective AIC criteria 
if(AIC(m2$lme) > AIC(m1$lme)){mod = m1}else{mod = m2} 
if(AIC(mod$lme) > AIC(m3$lme)){mod = m3}else{mod = mod}

return(mod$gam)
}

mod2 <- best.mod(dat = test_gam)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Conor

Comment: I think the error is get.models calling the dredge model objects because when run as: 

 `m1 <- dredge(gamm(Temp ~ s(Month, bs = "cc", k = k.month) +    s(Date, bs = 'cr') + Year,
                               data = dat, correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|Year, p = 1),
                               control = ctrl))`


the function does not crash with this error.

Answer (score 1):

`get.models` evaluates in model's `formula` environment, which in `gamm` is
(always?) `.GlobalEnv`, while it should be function's environment (i.e.
`sys.frames(sys.nframe())`).

So, instead of

```
get.models(ms, 1)
```

use

```
eval(getCall(ms, 1))
```